# How do i compare the 6 numbers inputted by the user to the 6 randomly generated numbers to see if they are the same or not

Tags: java, arrays

```
package lotto;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lotto {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int restarto = 0;
        double[] inputs = new double[6];

        do{
            ////////////////////////ask for input
            System.out.println("Welcome to the lotto program. Please enter " +inputs.length + " values:");
            for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
                inputs[i] = scan.nextDouble();

            ///////////////////////create random numbers
            double [] elArry = new double[6];
            Random random = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i < elArry.length; i++){
                elArry[i] = random.nextInt(101);
            }

            //////////////////////check for similarities
```

How can I compare the user inputted numbers and my randomly generated numbers to see if the user has correctly guessed the numbers?

```
            //////////////////////print results



            //////////////////////restart?
            System.out.println("Would you like to guess again on the same lotto numbers?");
            System.out.println("1.Yes");
            System.out.println("2.No");

            restarto=scan.nextInt();

        }while(restarto == 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: I would use `int[]` rather than `double[]`. One way is to sort both arrays and check the results are the same.

Comment: I'd suggest you make a `final int` for your array size (`6` constant). When working with both arrays, you can use this constant and not fear of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Improve formatting

Answer (score 1):

If necessary to know only if all were guessed right:

```
boolean same = true;    
for(int i = 0; i < elArry.length; i++) {
    if (elArry[i] != inputs[i]) {
        same = false;
        break;
    }
System.out.println(same? "You have guessed correctly!" : "You guessed wrong!");
```

If you are fine with making a method for that, like [robotlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5976941/robotlos) suggested, the code will be prettier:

```
private static boolean guessedRight() {
    for (int i = 0; i < elArry.length; i++)
        if (elArry[i] != inputs[i]) return false;
    return true;
}
...
System.out.println(guessedRight()? "You have guessed correctly!" : "You guessed wrong!");
```

But to tell the truth, you can generate random numbers straight after the user's input, which will make your code more compact:

```
boolean same = true;
for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i] = scan.nextInt();
    if(inputs[i] != random.nextInt()) same = false;
    //there is no reason to generate double if the user guesses with ints
}
//if same is false, at least one number was not guessed right
```

Comment: Shudder, break. Make it a method and have the method return instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the two arrays, then check to see if they equal. If they do, then they are the same:

```
Arrays.sort(inputs);
Arrays.sort(elArry);
return (Arrays.equals(inputs, elArry));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a boolean array of 6 then make a loop comparing the input and rndNum.

```
boolean[] correct = new boolean[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (inputs[i]==elArry[i]) {
        correct[i] = true;
    }
```

There are tons of ways to tackle this problem, this i guess is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since both arrays must have the same values in the same order, then yoy can check if they are technically equal

The class [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) has the equals method that can solve that for you...

## Example:

```
if (Arrays.equals(inputs, elArry)) {
    System.out.println("You won... :)");
} else {
    System.out.println("You were not even close... :(");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a loop to check if the i'th entry of your input array is also contained in elArray, providing you are not interested in the guessing order:

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (IntStream.of(elArray).anyMatch(x -> x == inputs[i])) {
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

Now the counter variable contains the amount of correctly guessed numbers. You could also modify this to keep track of which numbers were correct.